# I keep getting zero when i call getPixel function on the image Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-gallery, pixel, steganography

I have an image and store each pixel values in an array called pixels. I then get the first pixel value at location (0,0) and proceed to change only the RED value of the pixel to a specified integer. I then create a new array called encodedPixels which contains the changed value along with all the rest of the values from pixels array.

I create a new bitmap called encodedBitmap and set the encodedPixels onto this bitmap. I then call getPixels at (0,0), it should display the edited value with the changed red value, However it always displays zero and I cant seem to figure out why.
Below is how I have created the bitmap

```
   Bitmap encodedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageWidth,imageHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    encodedBitmap.setPixels(encodedPixels,0,imageWidth,0,0,imageWidth,imageHeight);


   System.out.println("first pixel at encodedbitmap: " + encodedBitmap.getPixel(0,0));
```

Comment: So, you are trying to make a **steganography** system.

Comment: Copying the pixel data of bitmaps multiple times begs for OutOfMemory exceptions

Comment: yes its a steganography project.. I have only copied it once and then set it onto the bitmap

Comment: I can successfully encoded my message after the (0,0) pixel e.g (1,0) , (2,0) ... changes value according to my message. I can then read the pixels and get that message back. However, Its just whenever i try to call getpixel(0,0) it returns a 0. This also happens when i try to store the message length in (1,0) instead of (0,0) which is confusing me

Comment: I ran through the application and followed the logcat and i found this message I dont know if it means anything `Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 183(8KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(16KB) LOS objects, 11% free, 32MB/36MB, paused 12.247ms total 37.146ms`

Comment: Can you post a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the whole process which replicates your result? Your method seems innocent enough and I can't suspect a problem anywhere down the line just with the current information given.

Comment: I have found a solution.. I simply just use setPixels(0,0) with the encoded message length **after** I have created the bitmap. Seems simple enough  but it was weird that I couldn't do it from when i created the Bitmap. Thanks for help guys

Comment: Consider writing that as an answer so that it's visible and future readers that run into the same problem can benefit, too.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution to this problem is to use the **SetPixel(int x,int y)** function **after** creating the bitmap with the desired pixel array. This helped me overcome the weird 0 value that I found in the first pixel (0,0).